# How to remove curve padding in flutter website?

Tags: flutter

I have built a website using flutter, everything is displaying the way I wanted untill I open the site in full screen view in my desktop browser. that is when a big curve will hear and over shadow some content of the website

[The View I'm getting in my Desktop browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpwzT.jpg)

Comment: please provide minimal reproduce code,

Comment: Are you using a BorderRadius or something? Please provides some code

Comment: I'm not using Border Radius. And the problem in not only in one screen but all the screens

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.
I'm using GetX for routing and by default fullscreenDialog is false, I fixed the issue by changing the fullscreenDialog to true in all screens.[This is how I fix the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HLUx.png)

```
  GetPage(
      fullscreenDialog: true,
      name: '/${AppRouteNames.login}',
      page: () => const LoginScreen(),
    ),
```